# Iterate over direction enum

Tags: c++, loops, enums, iterator

I have a direction enum with 6 direction entries (N, NE, SE, S, SW, NW) which are basicly the edges of a node in a graph. I often need to iterate over all neighbours which is currently done by iterating from 0->5 using an int only.

Sometimes one also needs to iterate from e.g. 2->1 wrapping around which is currently done by iterating from 2->2+5 and taking it mod 6 on use.

Is there anything I can to do make that safer/easier to use without losing performance? The for loops with fixed integer range can be unrolled, inlined etc. Vector based approaches can't (using a static const vector inside the enum)

I already have the enum in a scheme like:

```
struct Direction{
    enum Type{
        N, NE, ...
    }
    unsigned COUNT = ...;
    Type t_;
    operator Type(){return t_;}
    Direction(Type t):t_(t){assert(N<=t<COUNT);}
    explicit Direction(unsigned t):t_(t%COUNT){}
    static Direction fromUInt(unsigned t){return Direction(Type(t));}
}
```

So what I would like is having iterators that allow iterating efficiently over the whole set and also allow this for arbitrary start points in which case the iterator wraps around.

How could one write this? I can't figure anything out as I would have e.g. start=end for a whole loop which would be invalid. Or shall I just have start=givenStartType, end=start+COUNT and do a modulo on each iterator deref?

No C++11 allowed unfortunately

Comment: No there is no working code in the question. The code posted is merely the structure of an enum to which the question refers to. What is posted under the code are starting ideas not more

Answer (score 2):

**EDIT in response to clarification**

Your idea of taking the iterator modulo `COUNT` on each dereference is a good one. See the reverse iterator/iterable combination below. I inspected the assembly output after compiling with clang with `-O3`. The compiler unrolled the loop. The output is `2 1 0 5 4 3`. You can implement a forward iterator, or make the direction a parameter. You can also make this into a template over the enum type.

Unfortunately, from the point of view of usage syntax, I don't think this buys you all that much over a `do`-`while` loop as shown by the other answer – at least not before C++11. It does hide the various index variables, and helps you to avoid mistakes with them, but it is much more verbose.

```
#include <iostream>

struct Direction {
    enum Type {N, NE, SE, S, SW, NW};

    static const unsigned COUNT = 6;

    Type t_;

    operator Type() { return t_; }
    Direction(Type t) : t_(t) { }
    explicit Direction(unsigned t) : t_(Type(t % COUNT)) { }
};

struct ReverseIterable {
    const unsigned      start_;

    struct iterator {
        unsigned        offset_;

        explicit iterator(unsigned offset) : offset_(offset) { }

        Direction operator *() { return Direction(offset_); }
        iterator& operator++() { --offset_; return *this; }

        bool operator ==(const iterator &other)
            { return offset_ == other.offset_; }
        bool operator !=(const iterator &other) { return !(*this == other); }
    };

    explicit ReverseIterable(Direction start) : start_(start) { }

    iterator begin() { return iterator(start_ + Direction::COUNT); }
    iterator end() { return iterator(start_); }
};

int main()
{
    ReverseIterable     range = ReverseIterable(Direction::SE);

    for (ReverseIterable::iterator iterator = range.begin();
         iterator != range.end(); ++iterator) {

        std::cout << (int)*iterator << " ";
    }
    std::cout << std::endl;

    return 0;
}
```

In C++11, the loop could be:

```
    for (Direction direction : ReverseIterable(Direction::SE))
        std::cout << (int)direction << " ";
    std::cout << std::endl;
```

You can probably (ab?)use a macro to get something similar in C++98.

I've kept the original answer below for the time being, because it eases maintainability if the enum definition can change, and because it allows sparse ranges. A very similar iterator can be implemented on top of it.

---

**Original answer focused on safety**

This might be complete overkill for your purpose, and it might be ill-suited for a reason I will describe further down. However, you can use this library (disclaimer: I am the author): https://github.com/aantron/better-enums to write code like this:

```
#include <iostream>
#include <enum.h>

ENUM(Direction, int, N, NE, SE, S, SW, NW)

int main()
{
    size_t  iterations = Direction::_size();
    size_t  index = 2;

    for (size_t count = 0; count < iterations; ++count) {
        std::cout << Direction::_values()[index] << " ";
        index = (index + 1) % Direction::_size();
    }
    std::cout << std::endl;

    return 0;
}
```

Output:

```
SE S SW NW N NE
```

(The values were `int`-sized enums, but were converted to strings for output to `std::cout` only).

This shows an iteration over the whole set, with an arbitrary starting point. You could make this go forwards or backwards, and templatize it over any enum.

I think using modulo as in your question is a good idea. This code just gives you some reflective information about the number of constants in the enum, and also puts them in an array.

The reason this may be ill-suited is that, since you are not using C++11, the array `Direction::_values()` will be initialized at program start-up. I think loop unrolling can still happen, but the compiler won't be able to do anything with the contents of the array. The array will still be allocated statically, but the elements won't be available during compilation.

Should you later have the option to use C++11, the array will be basically the same as a statically-initialized `int[6]` (actually, `Direction[6]`, where `Direction` is a literal `struct` type).

(Actually, I suppose I could expose an array of `int`s instead of `Direction`s, which would be statically initialized even in C++98).

Comment: I already have 2 constructors taking integer arguments converting it to Direction. So I don't see any benefit here. Especially as I need a couple of more variables (at least count and index) See the edited question.

Comment: I see. I think I (and the other answerer) have been focusing on the safety part of your question, in the sense (we assumed) of resistance to changing the definition of the enum. I'll edit the question to sketch out an iterator.

Comment: Actually it seems your question already has the right idea for the iterators – do a modulo on each dereference. As I mentioned, I think that is the right thing to do. The point was to move the above code into a function or cut it up into iterators. I will still give an example, but is "do modulo on each dereference" sufficient as an answer? Since you already have `COUNT` and seem to be assuming a dense range, what is the remaining concern with safety?

Comment: That looks pretty good. Non-reverse iterable should be enough but reverse is a bonus. I'd dissallow constructing the Direction from int to avoid the extended modulo and do that in the iterator instead. One ideo to avoid negative numbers alltogether is using a start+COUNT as start instead. And you can probably do something like: for (ReverseIterable::iterator iterator = Direction::Iterable(Direction::NE).begin(); iterator != Direction::Iterable(Direction::NE).end(); ++iterator) or use a macro to simulate C++11 loops.

Comment: Good suggestions. I changed the code in the answer based on them, except for the macro – I just mentioned that, because recommending it would be controversial :) Also, if you think the reflective library is a bad idea as part of the answer, then, if you edit your question to say the constant range is assumed to be dense/contiguous, I will snip that text to keep the answer concise. It is just for other users who might have analogous questions at this point.

Answer (score 0):

If you're wanting to avoid a custom library, the approach I've generally seen used is something like this:

```
enum Direction
{
    SE,
    S,
    SW,
    NW,
    N,
    NE,

    DIRECTION_FIRST = SE,
    DIRECTION_LAST = NE,
}
```

Then you can use `DIRECTION_FIRST` and `DIRECTION_LAST` to properly iterate over the range. There is still room for error if someone adds values to the enum without updating the iteration endpoints, but centralizing it in the enum should make this less likely.

Now if you assume an arbitrary starting direction `start` you could iterate like this:

```
Direction current = start;
do
{
    // Do stuff with current...

    current = (current + 1) % DIRECTION_LAST;
} while(current != start);
```

(The logic would be a bit more complex, though still possible, if your enum doesn't start at 0. That's probably the only time you'd need to use `DIRECTION_FIRST`.)